# Lombok + Jackson Запись в файл класса с изменяемыми свойствами

Tags: java, jackson, lombok

Есть класс, поля которого изменяются с течением времени. Я хочу по нажатию кнопки записать класс в файл при помощи Jackson. Но я не хочу прописывать все геттеры и сеттеры вручную, поэтому использую lombok с аннотацией @Data.
В результате, в файл записываются только поля, имеющие реализованные пользовательские геттеры, а все остальные нет.
Поиск выдает примеры решения только для неизменяемых классов с аннотацией @Value. Вариант с @Biulder тоже не сработал.

Вот исходный класс:

```
@Data
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int growth;
    private int age;
    private double weight;

    public void setAge(int age){
        if ((age>5) & (age<100)) this.age=age;
    }
}
```

Записывается только поле age.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если так:

```
@lombok.Data
public class Person {
    @JsonProperty(value = "name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty(value = "growth")
    private int growth;
    @JsonProperty(value = "age")
    private int age;
    @JsonProperty(value = "weight")
    private double weight;

    public void setAge(int age){
        if ((age>5) & (age<100)) this.age=age;
    }
}
```

Comment: Работает! Только оригинальном классе около 30 свойств, к каждому приписывать @JsonProperty...Видимо придется все прописать ручками?

Comment: так а в чем проблема? это же просто скопировать аннотацию и подставить имя переменной. 2 минуты от силы. мало того, есть мнение, что именно так и нужно делать, потому как в этом случае переименование переменной не повлечет проблем с сериализацией-десириализаций (джейсон будет неизменен)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Не за что) Удачи